# Let $G$ be a group with identity e and distinct nonidentity elements $a$ and $b$ such that $b^3 = e$ and $(ba)^2 = e$. What is the order of $aba$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $G$ be a group with identity $e$ and distinct nonidentity elements $a$ and $b$ such that $b^3 = e$ and $(ba)^2 = e$. What is the order of $aba$?

This is what I did to answer this question. I want to make sure my justification is correct without any false assumptions or statements.

Knowing that $b^3 = e$ and $(ba)^2 = e$. I set

$$b^3 = (ba)^2$$

$$b^3 = b^2*a^2$$

$$b = a^2.$$ Since we know $b^3 = e$, then we can say $a^6 = e$.

Knowing $b^3 = e$, $(ba)^2 = e$, and $a^6 = e$ we can say the order of $aba$ is equal to 6.

$$(aba)^6 = (a^6)(b^6)(a^6)= (a^6)[a^2)(b^2)]^3=(e)*(e)^3=e.$$

Thank you for the help.

Comment: $(ba)^2=baba=e\implies aba = b^{-1}$

Comment: You can not assume the group is abelian.  You can not assume $baba = bbaa$.

Comment: Note:  your argument assumes that $G$ is abelian, though this was not stated.  Also, knowing that $g^6=e$ does not preclude a lower order.  All you could conclude was that the order of $g$ was $1,2,3$ or $6$.

Comment: @lulu Can you elaborate a little more on baba = e implies aba = b^(-1). I'm still trying to understand these concepts.

Comment: Ok, I'll post something below.

Comment: Take a look at what I posted below. Is it clear enough?  As an exercise, you might want to carefully write out the proof that the order of an element is also the order of its inverse.

Comment: Yes, your explanation makes sense. I will read into the proof of the order of an element is also the order of its inverse. This is my first theoretical math course so I'm having a slow start trying to switch gears out of application math. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with $$(ba)^2=baba=1$$  we multiply both sides on the left by $b^{-1}$ to get $$b^{-1}baba=b^{-1}e\implies aba = b^{-1}$$ since $b^{-1}b=e$.

So far we have not used the assumption that $b^3=e$.

Now, the order of any element in a group is also the order of its inverse.  To see that note that if $g^n=e$ then multiplication by $g^{-n}$ yields $e=g^{-n}$.  this proves that the order of $g^{-1}$ is no greater than the order of $g$, and switching the roles of $g,g^{-1}$ yields the opposite inequality.  Thus the order of $aba$ is the order of $b^{-1}$ which is also the order of $b$, so the desired answer is $\fbox 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Your justification is not correct. The first problem is that
$(ba)^2 = b^2 a^2$ is not true unless $a$ and $b$ commute. Remember we are not necessarily in an abelian group; $(ba)^2 = baba$ and you have to keep it in that order. Ignoring this, there is another problem, which is that you say $(aba)^6 = e$ and conclude the order of $aba$ is $6$. But it could just as easily be that the order of $aba$ is $1$, or $2$, or $3$.

To find the order of $aba$ we need to find the *smallest* $k$ such that $(aba)^k = e$, not just any $k$. The easiest approach, however, has already been suggested. Note that:

- Since $(ba)^2 = baba = e$, $aba = b^{-1}$.
- The order of $x$ and the order of $x^{-1}$ must be the same, for any $x$.